# How to refactor code into a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have logic in my model that I think would better be fit into a service class. It grabs a list of movies from an API. Ideally, I'd like this service class to do the same and seed the database. Currently, I call `Movie.create_all_from_api` in the `seeds.rb` file. I'm new to Rails so I'm wondering where to put this service class and where I should call the service. Do I put it in a `/app/service` folder?

**Movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
   require 'rest_client'
   has_many :reviews

   def self.create_all_from_api
      moviedata = retrieve_results
      moviedata['results'].each do |m|
        Movie.create(title: m['title'], release: m['release_date'], genre: m['genre'])
      end
   end

   def self.get_data(url)
      RestClient.get(url, { :content_type => :json})
   end

   def self.retrieve_results
      url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?page=1&language=en-US&api_key=s0m3n1c3k3y"
      JSON.parse(get_data(url))
   end

end
```

My proposed service class

```
class ApiService
   require 'rest_client'
   def self.create_all_from_api
      moviedata = retrieve_results
      moviedata['results'].each do |m|
         Movie.create(title: m['title'], release: m['release_date'], genre: m['genre'])
      end
   end

   def self.get_data(url)
      RestClient.get(url, { :content_type => :json})
   end

   def self.retrieve_results
      url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?page=1&language=en-US&api_key=s0m3n1c3k3y"
      JSON.parse(get_data(url))
   end
end
```

Comment: `app/services`.

Comment: i second @Anthony, you can even have subfolders in the services folder. Note, as you put your logic into a service, it is also good not to have all your logic in one service class, each service should have a single responisbility...you could have a service class to create data, and another for getting data. For further reference you can also check out this [link](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/09/services-what-they-are-and-why-we-need-them/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an `app/services/` folder.

Some comments I have (opinion-based for most of them) on your code:

- A service class usually define the instance method `perform`, so you use it like this: `RegisterUser.new(some, args).perform`
- Your current `ApiService` only contains class methods, so you don't need to instantiate that class. This is the purpose of a `module`, which cannot be instantiated but just provide methods.
- I would create a constant out of the url in your service object, like `URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org [...]".freeze` and use it then.
- several methods could be `private`
- the class/module name should be an action like `CreateUser`, `SendWelcomeEmail`, etc. Your current service object could be named `CreateMoviesFromJSONFeed`

Comment: I often add a class method for convenience: `def self.perform(args); new(args).perform; end`. This allows a client to call the class in a more natural style: `RegisterUser.perform(args)`.

Comment: You might also look in to the [interactor gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor), either to adopt it or just to learn from people who have thought a lot about service classes.

Comment: Thanks for your input, so would I still call the module method in `seeds.rb`?

Comment: It depends on when you want this to happen. If you want to seed you DB with that data, then yes. If you want to make sure it exists every time the rails environnement is loaded, then it could be in an initializer (but it would have to handle the possible duplicates).

Comment: Make sure you remove the api_key from the code as well and use an ENV  var.